# laravel where with like operator and percent doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

In laravel 5.6 I have `$ads`

```
$ads=Ad::whereIn('type',$type)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

and its value look like this :

```
[
{
    "id": 50,
    "title": "sssss",
    "description": "Et enim  provident. Eos animi illum ullam eaque aut.",
    "created_at": "2018-06-06 18:12:43",
    "updated_at": "2018-06-06 18:12:43"
},...
]
```

I want to search in this array;

when I write :

```
$titleSearchResult=collect($ads)->where('title','LIKE',"ssss");
```

I get the result true;

but when I write :

```
$titleSearchResult=collect($ads)->where('title','LIKE',"%ss%");
```

I don't get any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `where` method filters the collection by a given `key / value` pair, so if you want your query to work you should change it to something like this

```
$titleSearchResult=collect($ads)->where('title', 'ssss');
```

***Note:*** I'm not sure the `%` will work as they would in a LIKE statement, so let me know if it works :D
[Laravel Official docs explaining where method.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-where)

Comment: i found that.the collect method in laravel support three parameters (key,operator,value) but the operator can not be "LIKE".this operator just support >,=,< symbols.

Answer (score 1):

i find the problem myself:D

the `collect()->where()` method in laravel support three parameters (key,operator,value) but the operator can not be "LIKE".

this operator just support >,=,< symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the like into new version of laravel. This will give you filtered result directly.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'like', 'T%')
            ->get();
```

or in your case like below:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $like . '%')
            ->get();
```

Please check the document below for more details regarding where clauses:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

to perform a like query equivalent you could filter the collection.

```
$filtered = $ads->filter(function($value,$key){
   if(strpos($value['title'],'ss') !== false){
      return $value;
   }
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter